# Flask: how to render different template file based on url?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using Python Flask and I want to render a template file based on the given end of the url:

If I go to domain.com/posts/bla I want it to get bla.html and domain.com/posts/now get now.html, etc.

I tried to basically get the end part as variable and inject it as name for the file to get.

```
@app.route("/posts/<path>", methods=['GET'])
def article(path):
    return render_template("%s.html" % path)
```

Most solutions I found were about routing based on parameters but I don't want to render the same html file for this specific part.

The log says "TemplateNotFound: path.html". It seems to not inject the variable.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

- Apparently reloading UWSGI (= to serve Flask with Nginx) wasn't done properly and didn't pick up code changes. After restart it worked and the path variable worked.
- The html file I was using had a form. As I didn't passed a variable within the route that points to a form function, it didn't render the page. After swapping it with a minimal HTML file to test, it worked.